# UEFI edk2/FmpDevicePkg in tianocore crashed after excution

Tags: uefi

I built FmpDevicePkg in tianocore/edk2. Then, I load eif driver in EmulatorX64 and Minnow Board. It both crashed without any message.
I can set break point with Visual Studio for other driver/app packages. However, as for FmpDevicePkg, it can't set break point and crashed directly after I load the driver.
Does anyone know how to debug it? Or how can I test FmpDevicePkg driver? (or associated capsule)
Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Thanks!
I

Comment: This question needs more details. Examples of other drivers/apps you have tested. What does "crashed directly" mean? How? Show your steps.

Answer (score 0):

I traced the code and found out it hang at follows:

1. PcdGetBool (PcdTestKeyUsed);
2. PcdSetBoolS (PcdTestKeyUsed, TRUE);

Detail as follows:
\edk2\FmpDevicePkg\FmpDxe\ DetectTestKey.c

```
  DetectTestKey (
  VOID
  )
  {
   ….
  // If PcdTestKeyUsed is already TRUE, then skip test key detection
  //
  TestKeyUsed = PcdGetBool (PcdTestKeyUsed); -> system hang
  ..
  // If test key detected or an error occurred checking for the test key, then
  // set PcdTestKeyUsed to TRUE.
  //
  if (TestKeyUsed) {
    DEBUG ((DEBUG_INFO, "FmpDxe(%s): Test key detected in PcdFmpDevicePkcs7CertBufferXdr.\n", mImageIdName));
    PcdSetBoolS (PcdTestKeyUsed, TRUE);   -> system hang
```

I modified \MdeModulePkg\MdeModulePkg.dec  from

```
PcdsDynamic, PcdsDynamicEx]
  gEfiMdeModulePkgTokenSpaceGuid.PcdTestKeyUsed|FALSE|BOOLEAN|0x00030003
```

as below:

```
[PcdsPatchableInModule, PcdsDynamic, PcdsDynamicEx]
  gEfiMdeModulePkgTokenSpaceGuid.PcdTestKeyUsed|FALSE|BOOLEAN|0x00030003
```

It worked fine.